# Texture flickering in p5

Tags: p5.js

I have a scene with a cube and a custom obj. I am attempting to apply a gradient as a texture to the cube via createGraphics, but every time I use createGraphics as a texture on the cube it flickers

[image]

The custom model does not have the same issue when using the createGraphics texture for it, it is exclusively a problem with the cube.

Here is my code:

```
var camy;
var camz;
var camoffset;
var horiZon;
var c1;
var c2;

function preload() {
    fria = loadImage('nocity.png');
    island = loadModel('untitled.obj');
}
function setup() {
    canvas = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
    pixelDensity=1;
    c1 = color(255, 255, 255);
    c2 = color(0, 0, 0);
    sunset = createGraphics(200, 200);
}

function windowResized() {
      resizeCanvas(windowWidth,windowHeight);
}

function draw() {
    background(0, 5, 100);
    angleMode(DEGREES);

    camoffset = 2500 - windowWidth;
    horiZon = map(mouseY, 0, height, -35, -65);
    camx = map(mouseX, 0, width, -500, 500);
    camz = map(mouseY, height, 0, -1400 - camoffset, -2100 - camoffset);
    camy = map(mouseY, height, 0, -1000 - camoffset, -400);
    setGradient(0, 0, 200, 200, c1, c2);

    perspective(PI / 3.0, width / height, 0.1, 10000);
    camera(camx, camy, camz, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -0.25);
    translate(-2.5, 6, 0);
    rotateZ(180);
    rotateY(180);
    noStroke();
    texture(fria);
    model(island);
    texture(sunset);
    translate(0, 100, horiZon);
    box(200, 200, 1);
}

function setGradient(x, y, w, h, c1, c2) {
  noFill();
    for (var i = y; i <= y + h; i++) {
      var inter = map(i, y, y + h, 0, 1);
      var c = lerpColor(c1, c2, inter);
      sunset.stroke(c);
      sunset.line(x, i, x + w, i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem. When I removed the camera code, the flickering disappeared. So the solution I made was I instead used translation and rotation to emulate the camera motions that I wanted. It is quite hard to think of it this way, but you can figure out what translation you need to do with simple trig.